# The view getting loaded as separate page rather than in the kendo window after postback

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I have implemented the kendo popup window and loaded a view in it. When I try doing a postback the view gets loaded as a separate page and not in the window. How do I solve this issue.

**Get Method that loads the view in the window first time**

```
 public ActionResult RequestStatus(int requestId, string projectName, string countryCode)
        {
            RequestStatusUpdateViewModel reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel = new RequestStatusUpdateViewModel();

            reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel.RequestID = requestId;
            reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel.ProjectName = projectName;
            reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel.CountryCode = countryCode;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // return View("NewRequestView", Mapper.Map<RequestStatusViewModel>(newReqeustViewModel));
                return null;
            }
            return View("EditorTemplates/_RequestStatusView", Mapper.Map<RequestStatusUpdateViewModel>(reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel));

        }
```

**PostMethod**

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RequestStatus_Update(RequestStatusUpdateViewModel requestStatusUpdateViewModel)
        {

            WorkLogViewModel workLogViewModel = new WorkLogViewModel();
            WorkLogRepository workLogRepository = new WorkLogRepository();

            workLogViewModel.WorkLogAppliesToID = 1;
            workLogViewModel.WorkLogTypeCode = "60";
            workLogViewModel.RequestID = requestStatusUpdateViewModel.RequestID;
            workLogViewModel.WorkLogSubject = "Worklog created for Request " + requestStatusUpdateViewModel.RequestID;
            workLogViewModel.WorkLogDetails = requestStatusUpdateViewModel.WorkLogDetails;
            workLogViewModel.IsActive =true;


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("_RequestStatusView", Mapper.Map<RequestStatusUpdateViewModel>(requestStatusUpdateViewModel));
            }

            requestRepository.UpdateRequestStatus(Mapper.Map<RequestStatus>(requestStatusUpdateViewModel));
            workLogRepository.CreateWorkLog(Mapper.Map<WorkLog>(workLogViewModel));
            return PartialView("EditorTemplates/_RequestStatusView", Mapper.Map<RequestStatusUpdateViewModel>(requestStatusUpdateViewModel));

        }
```

**View**

```
@using System.Collections
@model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.RequestStatusUpdateViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<style>

    .statusButtonAlign{

        margin-top:20px;
         margin-right:10px;
         float:right;
    }

     #WorkLogDetails {
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm("RequestStatus_Update", "Request", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "requestStatusform" }))
{

<div class="k-popup-edit-form k-window-content k-content" >
    <div class="k-edit-form-container">
      @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CountryCode, new { data_bind = "value: CountryCode" })
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestStatus)
            </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.RequestStatusCode)

        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
        .DataTextField("Status")
        .Placeholder("Select...")
        .DataValueField("RequestStatusCode")
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Filter("contains")

        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

        .Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetRequestStatus", "Request").Data("GetCountryCodeFilter").Type(HttpVerbs.Post);

        }).ServerFiltering(true)


           )
                )
            </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkLogDetails)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.WorkLogDetails, new { htmlAttributes = new { cols = "100" } })
        </div>

        <div class="statusButtonAlign">
            <button type="submit" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-primary k-grid-update">Update</button>
            <button type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-cancel">Cancel</button>

        </div>

        </div>

</div>
}
<script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) and then use `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `Html.BeginForm`

Check out these examples:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-AjaxBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx

Comment: I tried this @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RequestStatus_Update", "Request", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp" })) . It still loads in a different page.

Comment: Could you tell me what do I need to specify in the AjaxOptions

Comment: it doesnt work even if i give @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RequestStatus_Update", "Request", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure",
}))

Comment: I cant see the javascript firing

Comment: function OnSuccess(response) {

        alert("Status Updated");
    }
    function OnFailure(response) {
        alert("Error occured.");
    }

Comment: I have finally managed to get to work. How do I put an inline message instead of showing an alert window

Comment: You can add a div with id='statusMessage' and then do something like OnSuccess(response) { $("#statusMessage").text("Status updated"); }

Comment: the div aproch is the best basicly tell your ajax from to replace the content of the div with the response instead of navigating